# LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file "zz.exe"

Tags: assembly, masm, dosbox

I wrote a simple piece of code and have been trying to build a executable file using ml.exe in masm32 sdk.But it kept giving me the following.Also my pc runs on win7 64bit. There is no executable file created any folder i looked.

[image]

**here is the code in zz.asm**

```
f segment
v:  
    int 21h 
f ends  
end v
```

this page is partially blocked in prc because the page retrieve jquery.min.js from a google server...took me a while to successfully post this.

Comment: You are using a 32-bit linker to link 16-bit code.  http://bytepointer.com/masm/ml611_errmsg.htm

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like `ml` passes some wrong arguments to `link.exe`. What you can do is:

> ml /nologo /coff d:\zz.asm /link /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /entry:v

And change your entry point to be `_v`

```
f segment
_v:  
    int 21h 
f ends  
end _v
```

[image: compile ok]

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
ml d:\zz.asm /link /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE
```

Comment: Could you try to first assemble it by using `ml /omf d:\zz.asm` and then use `link`? Also if you can, update your tools, like Bo Persson suggested.